# Custom navigator pop to parent

Tags: flutter

I have a Page 1, which opens the Page 2.

The page 2 has a `Navigator Widget` which changes in the same context some widgets.

This works nice, but Im trying to exit from the Page 2 to the Page 1.

The following code does not work:

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Any idea of how can I go back to page 1? Thanks

Comment: most likely you need a sort of custom [NavigatorObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html)

Comment: @pskink can you explain me how to exit from the "scope" of the Navigator widget and pop back to the page 1 using a NavigatorObserver?

Comment: by implementing [didPop](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver/didPop.html) method, just google for `NavigatorObserver` - for example https://medium.com/@najeira/how-to-handle-screen-transitions-in-flutter-b39dcb2675f but try the other ones too - the base idea is to observe your custom inner navigator and when popped call a `pop()` on the main outer navigator - or i just misunderstood your idea....

Comment: And how can I call the "main" navigator? using a key?

Comment: using [Navigator.of](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/of.html) - you need to have its `BuildContext`

Comment: Im trying it but is not working: Navigator.of(contextParentNavigator).pop();

Comment: `"not working"` means: does nothing, throws exception, blocks the whole app, anything else? are you sure it is called in the right place?

Comment: Ok sorry, my fault, I was using a gesture detector over a BackButton, using Navigator.of(contextParentNavigator).pop() works, you can answer it if you want, thanks.

Comment: good, your welcome to post a self answer then...

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate from page A to page B, and Page B has a custom navigator then if you need to access the Root Navigator just use this

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, thanks to the comment of @pskink I achieve to pop the page 2 using:

```
Navigator.of(contextParentNavigator).pop()
```

Comment: and you are not using `NavigatorObserver`?